# Entity Framework Fluent API map DbSet<> value to custom object in table

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

The title may be a bit confusing.
But the problem is:

Due database optimalization we have choose to design an ERD for the database which is in some aspects different from the class diagram.

Database erd:
[image: This is the ERD]

Class diagram:
[image]

Okay, the problem is; how to map DailyLog database entity to the DailyLog C# domain class. 
Because of performance optimalization we choose to store HeartRate in the database as a CLOB. And in the domain classes, it is easier to have the object in a list of a specific class type.

How to get this done in a nice and clean way?
I really don't know how to map this kind of database entity(s) to the domain classes.

The plan is to store heartrates this way: String: "07:00:01,50;07:00:02,52";

I have experimentend with DTO's but then I have to create a whole new layer of DTO's between Domain classes and Entity Framework. And I think there is a much cleaner way to do this. But I don't know how.

Comment: Why not just use Code first? It usually does a pretty good job of database optimization. By the way, what are you trying to optimize?

Comment: Yeah, we measure the person's heart rate each second. If I let EF create my database, I will get a table for "HeartRatePattern" with the properties, and in the worst situation there are records for each second created per user in the database. That is the reason why I want to map this to the DailyLog entity in a CLOB or large text field in the DailyLog entity

Answer (score 1):

You could use EF Fluent API. Check [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-entity-mappings-using-fluent-api.aspx) link for details. In your case the mapping should be something like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<DailyLog>().Map(m =>
    {
        m.Properties(p => new { p.Id, p.Date});
        m.ToTable("DAILYLOG");
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<HeartRatePattern>().ToTable("DAILYLOG").Property(x => string.Join(";",x.HeartRate)).HasColumnType("varchar");
}
```

Comment: Hi JanneP, thanks for the answer. Think this is a step forward. But I have a List<> with heartbeats from a different class and want to map this as a String in the database. I have already created a converter class which takes a List of heartbeats and it creates a string with key value pairs of it which has to be stored in the DailyLog entity in the database as a nvarchar(max).

Comment: I want something like this:


`modelBuilder.Entity<DailyLog>().Map(m =>
   {
    m.Properties(p => new { p.Id, p.Date, HeartRateConverter.Convert(p.HeartRatePatterns)});
    m.ToTable("DailyLogs");
   });`

But this is not possible in this way.

Comment: I edited my answer to include an idea for your HeartRate mapping. Haven't had the time to test it though.